# ASP.Net publishing masterpage to a server directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, error-handling

I have a domain and I already published my application to that domain. I have an admin part for the application, that I need to publish to a directory named admin on the server. When I had done that it shows a parser error... Error listed below

**Server error in '/' Application**

**Description**: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

```
**Parser Error Message**: The file '/billbox_admin.master' does not exist.
```

**Source Error**:

```
 Line 1:  <%@ page title="" language="C#" masterpagefile="~/billbox_admin.master" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="_Default, App_Web_12hmavcr" %>
 Line 2:  
 Line 3:  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="index_header" Runat="Server">
```

**note** :  my application and admin part are two different website projects
need immediate attention

Comment: Is master page exists at the root location?

Comment: Well, did you verify that "~/billbox_admin.master" exists on the server? By the way, you don't publish sites to a domain. You publish sites to a server, your domain name just points to the server's IP address.

Comment: @mason: yes it exists on the server,but as a file in the subdirectory of the root

Answer (score 0):

If your two sites are separate projects, then its likely your IIS website isn't configured properly. When you create an application (website) it sees all those folders and files as part of that website, if you have a separate website inside one of those folders, you have to add it as an application. I have encountered this before and solved it by right-clicking on the website name and clicking "Add Application..."

Your master page is likely at the root of your admin website, but because it is not in an "application" it is using the root directory of your main site instead, where that file does not exist.